# Docker: Connection timeout when connecting to database container

Tags: symfony, docker, docker-compose

I'm having an issue with my php container not connecting to my database container.

**My docker-compose.yml :**

```
version: "2"

    volumes:
      # this is the mysql data volume we are going to host the data inside
      dev_mysql_data:
      # This volume is used for elasticsearch
      dev_elastic_search:

    networks:
      mp_pixel:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
          driver: default
          config:
            - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16

    services:
      # database container for local development purposes
      dev_database:
        image: mysql:5.6
        networks:
          mp_pixel:
            aliases:
              - database
        ports:
          # port 3304 (external) is for use on your desktop sql client
          # port 3306 (internal) is for use inside your application code
          - 3304:3306
        volumes:
          # mount the mysql_data docker volume to host the local development database
          - dev_mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
          # the provision file helps when trying to use the provision script to clone databases
          - ./provision.cnf:/provision.cnf
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pixel

      # This is the local development version of the nginx container
      dev_nginx:
        image: mp-pixel-nginx:latest
        build: ./nginx
        ports:
          - '80:80'
          - '443:443'
        networks:
          mp_pixel:
            aliases:
              - nginx
        depends_on:
          - dev_phpfpm
        volumes_from:
          - dev_phpfpm
        environment:
          - VIRTUAL_HOST=~^(mp-pixel|mp-location|mp-feedback|mp-user|mp-phone|mp-loancalculator|mp-seo|mp-media|mp-listing|mp-development|mp-kpi|mp-newsletter|mp-auth|mp-worker|mp-search)-ph-dev.pixel.local

      # This is the local development version of the phpfpm container
      dev_phpfpm:
        image: mp-pixel-phpfpm:latest
        build:
          context: ./
          args:
            # this build might fail, if so, run in a terminal: export SSH_KEY=$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
            - SSH_KEY=$SSH_KEY
        networks:
          mp_pixel:
            aliases:
              - phpfpm
        depends_on:
          - dev_database
        volumes:
          # we override the images /www directory with the code from the live machine
          - ./:/www
        env_file:
          # inside this file, are the shared database secrets such as username/password
          - ./env/common
          - ./env/dev

      dev_elasticsearch:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.3.3
        networks:
          mp_pixel:
            aliases:
              - elasticsearch
        ulimits:
          memlock:
            soft: -1
            hard: -1
          nofile:
            soft: 65536
            hard: 65536
        mem_limit: 1g
        cap_add:
          - IPC_LOCK
        volumes:
          - dev_elastic_search:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        ports:
          - 9200:9200
        environment:
          - cluster.name=dev-elasticsearch-pixel
          - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
          - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
          - "xpack.security.enabled=false"
```

I run it with `docker-compose up` and the php logs show

`An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out`

I try to access the database container with `docker exec`, and I can confirm that I have the right credentials.

What could be the problem?

Comment: How did you conigure the database access? Can you share the DSN?

Comment: pls share connection string to db

Answer (score 0):

When your containers are up, did you already try to connect to the database with a tool like Sequel Pro? Maybe the database is just not initialized and because of this, the connection from the php container can't be established? You tried to access the db container but not the database itself.

Additionally you could add some more environment variables to the database section of your docker-compose.yml

```
  environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=databasename
      - MYSQL_USER=databaseuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=databasepassword
```

Hope that helps